# Multiple conditionals without repeating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

Wondering if there is a cleaner method of doing a conditional when a variable can equal 4, 6 or 8 without repeating previous inputs?

For example.

```
<%= form_with(model: sale, local: true) do |f| %>
 <% if @sale.cost == 4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_4 %>
 <% elsif @sale.cost == 6 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_5 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_6 %>
 <% elsif @sale.cost == 8 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_5 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_6 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_7 %>
   <%= f.text_field :sale_8 %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So the above is repeating the previous inputs (i.e.. `<%= f.text_field :sale_1 %>`, `<%= f.text_field :sale_2 %>`) for each statement. Is there a way to state that if `@sale.cost == 6` then add on the two required inputs following the previous 4? For example:

```
<%= form_with(model: sale, local: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @sale.cost == 4 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_3 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_4 %>
  <% some statement @sale.cost == 6 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_5 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_6 %>
  <% some statement @sale.cost == 8 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_7 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_8 %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on your logic, but in this specific case, if your conditionals are real, like the numbers you put, it can be as simple as

```
<%= form_with(model: sale, local: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @sale.cost >= 4 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_3 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_4 %>
  <% if @sale.cost >= 6 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_5 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_6 %>
  <% if @sale.cost >= 8 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_7 %>
    <%= f.text_field :sale_8 %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ahh it's that simple. Thanks for help.

Comment: what is "some statement" here?

Comment: sorry @emaillenin, I just copy/paste the code from the question and didn't removed it before, but it's edited now.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
<% if [4,6,8].include?(@sale.cost) %>
  <% @sale.cost.times do |i| %>
    <%= f.text_field :"sale_#{i+1}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You replace `"sale_#{i+1}".to_sym` with `:"sale_#{i+1}"` if you wanted to. And `@sale.cost.times.each do |i|` could be just `@sale.cost.times do |i|`.

Comment: `[4,6,8].include? 5` will return false so it want create any text fields if `@sale.cost` is 5

Comment: yes, we should not create text fields when sale cost is 5. Check the question. when sale cost is 5, none of the if condition will be true, so no text fields will be created